# Archilogic embed floor plan with next js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-import, archilogic

I am trying to use Archilogic embed module to show 3d floorplan in my next.js project.

I am trying below code and it says : `TypeError: ArchilogicEmbed is not a constructor`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

//import ArchilogicEmbed from "@archilogic/embed-api";

const Archilogic = () => import("@archilogic/embed-api");
const ArchilogicEmbed = dynamic(Archilogic, {
  ssr: false,
});



export default function Dashboard() {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function demo() {
      
      const embedEl = document.getElementById('mapid')
       const embedEl = document.getElementById("mapid");
      const viewer = ArchilogicEmbed(embedEl, {
        transparentBackground: true,
        //presentationMode: PresentationMode.jumpToCameraDefault,
        minimap: false,
        showTitle: false,
        showLogo: false,
        lowResTexturesOnly: false, // prevent hi-res textures from loading, gives a loading-time performance boost at the cost of visual quality
        bookmarksActive: false, // control whether the bookmarks menu should be open or closed
        uiButtons: {
          birdMode: false,
          personMode: false,
          fullscreen: false,
          bookmarkStrip: false,
          share: false,
          help: false,
          presentation: false,
          exportImage: false,
        },
      });

      // await for the viewer embed to be ready
      await viewer.viewerReadyPromise.catch((err) =>
        console.error("viewer couldnt be initialized", err)
      );

      const demoSceneId = <sceneId>;
      const publishableToken = <token>;
      const tokenOptions = { publishableToken };
      await viewer.loadScene(demoSceneId, tokenOptions).catch((err) => {
        // scene couldn't be loaded - it may be private or the ID couldn't be found
        console.error("There was an error loading the scene:", err);
      });
    }

    demo();
  }, []);

}
```

How do I use ArchilogicEmbed with Next.js?

[Here is the link](https://developers.archilogic.com/3d-embed-api/guide.html#installation) I am following.
The example on this link shows ArchilogicEmbed as constructor to initialize viewer and then show it on the page.

Here is codesandbox [example from Archilogic](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-demo-6ne6t?file=/main.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it using dynamic import, a slightly different method than what juliomalves suggested here.

I made another file with regular import, but calling it dynamically on the client side. as below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default function FloorPlan3D() {
  const Map3D = dynamic(() => import("./floorplan"), {
    loading: () => <p>A map is loading</p>,
    ssr: false, // This line is important. It's what prevents server-side render
  });

  return <Map3D />;
}
```

Comment: If you use this approach make sure to move the `dynamic(...)` call [outside the function, to the top level](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#basic-usage) of that file.

Answer (score 1):

`next/dynamic` is used to dynamically import *React* components. To dynamically import regular JavaScript libraries you can simply use [ES2020 dynamic `import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import).

You also need to rename your `publishableToken` option to `publishableAccessToken`, as that's the expected syntax.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Dashboard() {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function demo() {
            // Dynamically importing `@archilogic/embed-api`
            const ArchilogicEmbed = (await import("@archilogic/embed-api")).default;
            // Target the `demoId` element
            const embedEl = document.getElementById("demoId");
            const viewer = new ArchilogicEmbed(embedEl, {
                // Your options here
            });

            await viewer.viewerReadyPromise.catch((err) =>
                console.error("viewer couldn't be initialized", err)
            );

            const publishableAccessToken = "<your-token>"; // Replace with your token
            const sceneId = "<your-sceneId>"; // Replace with your scene ID
            await viewer
                .loadScene(sceneId, { publishableAccessToken })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error("There was an error loading the scene:", err);
                });
        }

        demo();
    }, []);

    return <div id="demoId"></div>;
}
```

Comment: I am just trying to make production build and it fails with an error " window is not defined".. local build works fine. what could be the reason now? thanks for your answer

Comment: Error : > Build error occurred
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../Documents/.../node_modules/@archilogic/embed-api/dist/embed.js:1:844)

Comment: Are you trying to use `@archilogic/embed-api` anywhere outside `useEffect`?

Comment: Yes on the other page where I use it as usual import. And I dynamic import that page to the actually page when using it. Do you think I should dynamic import the actual one as well ?